# how to do sort in nested array javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const res = [
  {
    _id: '5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6',
    first_name: 'AAA',
    last_name: 'BBBB',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144',
        timestamp: 1630931311227,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:28:31.227Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547',
    first_name: 'DDD',
    last_name: 'FFFF',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '613609414255d84bcb4a7122',
        timestamp: 1630931265409,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:45.409Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8',
    first_name: 'EEEE',
    last_name: 'FFFF',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '613609184255d84bcb4a710a',
        timestamp: 1630931224383,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:04.383Z'
      },
      {
        _id: '613709f49223350dfdaec618',
        timestamp: 1630996980379,
        expire_at: '2021-09-07T06:43:00.379Z'
      },
      {
        _id: '61372d81c0a7ec4fa0f7a8e3',
        timestamp: 1631006081890,
        expire_at: '2021-09-07T09:14:41.890Z'
      }
    ]
  }
];

res.forEach((val, key) => {
  console.log('val', val.story);
  val.story.sort((a, b) =>
    a.timestamp > b.timestamp ? 1 : b.timestamp > a.timestamp ? -1 : 0
  );
});
```

I want to sort the object based on story's timestamp. who has posted latest story it should come first for example EEE has latest story post it should come at first place.

this object should be at first place after that others which false later this story and so on

```
{
    _id: '5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8',
    first_name: 'EEEE',
    last_name: 'FFFF',
    story: [....]
  }
```

Comment: 1. Find out the most recent story in each object. 2. Copy its _id directly inside its parent object in a new key, for instance in `most_recent_story`. 3. Sort by `most_recent_story`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const res = [ { _id: '5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6', first_name: 'AAA', last_name: 'BBBB', story: [ { _id: '6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144', timestamp: 1630931311227, expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:28:31.227Z' } ] }, { _id: '5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547', first_name: 'DDD', last_name: 'FFFF', story: [ { _id: '613609414255d84bcb4a7122', timestamp: 1630931265409, expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:45.409Z' } ] }, { _id: '5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8', first_name: 'EEEE', last_name: 'FFFF', story: [ { _id: '613609184255d84bcb4a710a', timestamp: 1630931224383, expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:04.383Z' }, { _id: '613709f49223350dfdaec618', timestamp: 1630996980379, expire_at: '2021-09-07T06:43:00.379Z' }, { _id: '61372d81c0a7ec4fa0f7a8e3', timestamp: 1631006081890, expire_at: '2021-09-07T09:14:41.890Z' } ] } ];

function getEarliest(obj) {
    return obj.reduce((latest, e) => Math.max(latest, e.timestamp), 0)
}
const sorted = res.sort((a,b) => {
    return getEarliest(b.story) - getEarliest(a.story)
})
console.log(sorted)
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

```js
const res = [
  {
    _id: '5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6',
    first_name: 'AAA',
    last_name: 'BBBB',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144',
        timestamp: 1630931311227,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:28:31.227Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547',
    first_name: 'DDD',
    last_name: 'FFFF',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '613609414255d84bcb4a7122',
        timestamp: 1630931265409,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:45.409Z'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8',
    first_name: 'EEEE',
    last_name: 'FFFF',
    story: [
      {
        _id: '613609184255d84bcb4a710a',
        timestamp: 1630931224383,
        expire_at: '2021-09-06T12:27:04.383Z'
      },
      {
        _id: '613709f49223350dfdaec618',
        timestamp: 1630996980379,
        expire_at: '2021-09-07T06:43:00.379Z'
      },
      {
        _id: '61372d81c0a7ec4fa0f7a8e3',
        timestamp: 1631006081890,
        expire_at: '2021-09-07T09:14:41.890Z'
      }
    ]
  }
];

let getRecent = (story) => Math.max(...story.map(s => s.timestamp))
  
  res.sort((a, b) =>{
as =getRecent(a.story);
bs =getRecent(b.story);
   return as > bs ? 1 : bs > as ? -1 : 0
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to sort the nested story array, sort by big timestamp. Then sort the first layer array by comparing the timestamp of first element of each object

```
    res.forEach(function (element) {
        element.story.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
        })
    })
    res.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (b.story[0].timestamp - a.story[0].timestamp)
    })
    console.log(res);
```